How to do parameterization for cylindrical cordinates
Let $S$ be the plain $x = z$, $Q$ be the shape $4z^2 + x^2 + y^2=1$.
I have a really hard time transforming these $2$ equations to cylindrical coordinates. I managed these:
$$S: p = p, \theta=t, z = p\cos t$$
$$Q: p = 1, \theta=s, z = \sqrt{1-p^2}/2$$
A. Is it correct?
B: How do I show in cylindrical coordinates the intersection between them?
Thanks.

Do you really need to do it in cylindral coordinates ? The most complicated is Q, looking at his ovoid shape I would put the vertical axis of the cylinder coordinates alongside z

It is the assignment
